# Controlling Motorola Razr's buttons backlights

Tags: android, motorola, led, fileobserver

I'm trying to develop an application to keep my button's led always on when I turn on the screen.

I already get a functioning app for rooted phones by writing a Service and a BroadcastReceiver to be alarmed when screen status changes.

My problem now is that by default it seems that these lights are automatically controlled by OS using light sensor informations, so my work is broken by this behaviour.

Is there a way (from by searches seems not) of using a FileObserver to monitor system files ("/sys/class/leds/keyboard-backlight/brightness" in my case) modifications?

Thanks in advance for your help!